# Uncheck radio button in accordion function

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an accordion as such: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaBH7/1/)

The problem is that using `removeAttr('checked');` doesn't seem to work. I'm also unsure on how to get the relevant radio (`$(this).prev("input")` doesn't seem to be the right one)--I know that's a source of the problem, but trying this by selecting a set id (eg. `$("#1")` doesn't work either. I've also tried using `.prop` and just plain `.checked = false` to no avail.

Comment: You should probably use `.prop('checked', false);` instead of `.removeAttr("checked")`, but I got a little confused - isn't the whole idea of radio buttons is that they're automatically being unchecked when you check another radio button with the same name? You don't have to use any script language for this.

Comment: You don't have to remove the checked attribute since you can check only one radiobutton of the same name at a time, If you create a radiobuttons of same 'name' attribute , it forms a group and you can check only one at a time

Comment: Don't ever use just a number as an ID.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eaBH7/7/

Comment: @Itay `.prop('checked', false)` doesn't work but for the unchecked thing, I mean that I want to uncheck the radio that had already been checked--so if I click on the same radio twice, besides the menu sliding up again, I would like it to be displayed as if it were unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up some things... The main issue was that you were using `.prev()` assuming `this` is the `label`, while it was the `containing div`. Also you have to use `.preventDefault()` to stop the `radio button` from being checked again.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/eaBH7/9/)

```
$(this).find("input").prop('checked', false);
e.preventDefault();
```